# Factory method pattern for an embedded system

Tags: c++, embedded

I implemented an inheritance design using a base class

```
// Msg.hpp
#ifndef __MSG_H_
#define __MSG_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Msg {
  public:
    virtual void buildMsg(std::string &msg) = 0;
};
#endif
```

and in my example, two derived classes:

```
// GoodMorningMsg.hpp
#ifndef __GOOD_MORNING_MSG_H_
#define __GOOD_MORNING_MSG_H_

#include "Msg.hpp"
class GoodMorningMsg : public Msg {
  public:
    void buildMsg(std::string &msg) {
       msg.append("Good Morning");
    };
};
#endif

// GoodEveningMsg.hpp
#ifndef __GOOD_EVENING_MSG_H_
#define __GOOD_EVENING_MSG_H_

#include "Msg.hpp"
class GoodEveningMsg : public Msg {
  public:
    void buildMsg(std::string &msg) {
       msg.append("Good Evning");
    };
};
#endif
```

in order to avoid the need of *switch*, i would normally place instances from *GoodMorningMsg* and *GoodEveningMsg* classes in an std::map object and each time execute the relevant object to build my message.

Since i am writing code for an embedded system, I am not allowed to use dynamic allocation (in other words, the STL libraries).

Assuming I know in advance the size of instance i need to create, how could I implement a generic code and avoid the use of switches in my code?

**UPDATE**
I solve one question that i had, but the second part is still open.
Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "Const.hpp"
#include "Msg.hpp"
#include "GoodMorningMsg.hpp"
#include "GoodEveningMsg.hpp"

void printMsg( std::map<std::string, Msg*> msgMapObject , std::string msg , const std::string & strToFind ) {
    std::map<std::string, Msg*>::iterator it = msgMapObject.find( strToFind );
    if(it != msgMapObject.end()) {
        it->second->buildMsg( msg );
        std::cout << "Message: " << msg << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    GoodMorningMsg goodMorningMsg = GoodMorningMsg();
    GoodEveningMsg goodEveningMsg = GoodEveningMsg();

    std::map<std::string, Msg*> msgMap;

    msgMap.insert(std::make_pair( std::string("GoodMorning") , &goodMorningMsg ) );
    msgMap.insert(std::make_pair( std::string("GoodEvening") , &goodEveningMsg ) ) ;

    std::string msg("I wish you ");

    printMsg( msgMap , msg , std::string("GoodMorning") );
    printMsg( msgMap , msg , std::string("GoodEvening") );

    return 0;   
}
```

Instead of every time to create an instance of GoodMorningMsg or GoodEveningMsg class, i would like to place those something equivalent to std::map, but which can't throw an exception, since i am programming for embedded system application.

Comment: if you have to decide at run-time, I don't see any way of avoiding virtual calls/dynamic allocation, but I may be wrong (as I learn to never say never in C++ :) ) If you decide at compile time, then you can use a variety of techniques, probably using tags will be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly implement an abstract Msg class. Derive all three classes Msg, GoodMorningMsg, GoodEveningMsg. Templatise the Msg class and when instantiating passing either the GoodMorningMsg class or the GoodEveningMsg class and designing the Msg class abstract methd to call the buildMsg method of the type passed in. That said im not sure how that would solve your problem, then again im not sure I completely understand your problem

Comment: thank you for your answer. Class Msg is my base class and GoodMorningMsg and GoodEveningMsg are my derived classes.